# Polars - How to use `pl.when` to output a string value

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to use polars' [`pl.when`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) to create a new string column.  Based on a condition, the column should contain `"string a"` or `"string b"`.

Polars seems to interpret `"string a"` as a column, when I try the following.

```
pl.when(condition)
.then('string a')
.otherwise('string b')
.alias('new column')
```

**Output.**

```
ColumnNotFoundError: string a
```

I am expecting an output like this:

| new column |
| --- |
| string a |
| string b |

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the string into a [`pl.lit`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html) to ensure it is interpreted as a literal value.

```py
pl.when(cond).then(pl.lit('string a')).otherwise(pl.lit('string b'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Hericks answers, here is a full example for reference:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"values": [5, 15, 10]})
result = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("values") > 10)
    .then(pl.lit("string a"))
    .otherwise(pl.lit("string b"))
    .alias("new column")
)

print(result)
```

The output is the following:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬────────────┐
│ values ┆ new column │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ str        │
╞════════╪════════════╡
│ 5      ┆ string b   │
│ 15     ┆ string a   │
│ 10     ┆ string b   │
└────────┴────────────┘
```